# Mapping a type to a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, dictionary

I want to map new instances of a type to the content of a list.
For example:

```
MyList = [1..10]
data MyType = MyType Int

map (MyType (\x -> x)) MyList
```

I want to get something like [MyType, MyType ...] in which every MyType Int value come from the list.
This doesn't work, how can I achieve this? Or there are better way?

Thank you!

edit: I forgot that MyType is more complex, for example:

```
data MyType = MyType Int String Bool
```

so, how can I map just the ints in the list to the Int part of MyType keeping the other values fixed like MyType ... "test" True (that's why I thought of lambda).

Comment: Terminology note: in Haskell an instance (of a type class) is a type, not a value. So, instead of "map new instances of a type to the content of a list", you should just say "make values of a type from the content of a list", or (taking for granted Lee's answer) "map a constructor over a list".

Comment: @Manuel: You should read the Gentle Introduction to Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MyType` constructor is a function `Int -> MyType` so you can just use

```
let mapped = map MyType MyList
```

If you have a more complicated type e.g. `MyType Int String Bool` then you can do:

```
let mapped = map (\i -> MyType i "test" True) MyList
```

Comment: What if MyType is defined as MyType Int String Bool, but I want to keep String and Bool to a fixed value, for example: map MyType MyList "test" True ?

Comment: @Manuel `map (\x -> MyList x "test" True) myList` or `[MyList x "test" True | x <- myList]`.

Comment: So simple... Thank you very much to you all, I'm new to haskell and sometime I forget some details...

Answer (score 0):

When writing `data MyType = MyType Int` you are declaring a *type* `MyType with a single *constructor*`MyType`which takes an`Int`and create an object of type`MyType`.

The sometimes confusing part is that the convention is to use the same name for the type and the constructor when there is only one - like you did. You could perfectly write:

```
data MyType = MyConstructor Int
```

In this case, as @Lee pointed out, `MyConstructor` is a function of type `Int -> MyType` so you can just pass it as first argument of the `map` function.